# Spring Boot external DataSource bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I am trying to create a common library that includes several stuff needed by my microservices. One of those things is the ACL functionality provided with spring-security. My initial thought was to initialize all ACL-related beans from a @Configuration file in the common library and each time a microservice needs this functionality i could use the @Import annotation(to my microservice project) to "enable" it.

Some of these beans require the famous javax.sql.DataSource to work, so in my **common** library i autowired it as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AclConfiguration {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource
```

When i decide that i want this configuration to take place i go to my microservice project (let's say RulesApplication) and on the main class (annotated with @SpringBootApplication) i do the following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@Import(AclConfiguration.class)
public class RulesApplication {

.
.
.
```

The problem is that the DataSource bean cannot be seen from the common library, although it is being created as expected (validated just by removing the @Import).

Everytime i import the configuration from the common library i get a :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Indicating that the DataSource bean is null.

What am i missing here?

Comment: although it is being created as expected (validated just by removing the @Import) => after removal, whats the behavior?

Comment: The RulesApplication runs as expected, since all the DatasourceConfiguration is being handled by Spring, but with no ACL functionality. Is it clear, reading my question, that AclConfiguration.class is not part of the RulesApplication project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming up from some digging.. **There was never a real problem with the DataSource bean**. All the frustration was created by double-defining another Bean in the same class, which led to all the @Autowired beans failure to initialize.

As a result from this research(as other posts mentioned) the bean initialization is working smoothly between shared projects, so most of the times this error will occur from double-defining/badly-defining other beans.